# How to automatically increment a custom id with starting value in Ruby on Rails 5?

Tags: html, css, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a migration and I remove the default `'id'` for each table. I created a special field instead `'student_id'` and I want to make it auto increment starting with 1001.

Here is my code:

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_table :students, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer "student_id"
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => ' ', :null => false
      t.string "birthday"
      t.string "subjects"
      t.string "teachers"
      t.string "username", :limit => 25
      t.string "password_digest", :limit => 40
      t.timestamps
    end
    execute "CREATE SEQUENCE students_student_id_seq OWNED BY students.student_id INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1001"
  end

  def down
  drop_table :students
  execute "DELETE SEQUENCE students_student_id_seq"
  end

end
```

I got the ff error:

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEQUENCE students_student_id_seq OWNED BY students.student_id INCREMENT BY 1 STA' at line 1

How to auto a custom id increment with starting value in Ruby on Rails 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
execute "CREATE SEQUENCE students_student_id_seq OWNED BY students.student_id INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1001"
```

The above is Postgresql syntax and your database seems to be MySQL.

Anyway, you can achieve what you want by setting `student_id` as a primary key and then updating the increment starting value.

```
def change
  create_table :students, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "student_id", primary_key: true
    t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
    t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
    t.string "email", :default => ' ', :null => false
    t.string "birthday"
    t.string "subjects"
    t.string "teachers"
    t.string "username", :limit => 25
    t.string "password_digest", :limit => 40
    t.timestamps
  end

  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up { execute "ALTER TABLE students AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Is that all? or do I need to put the student_id field to be specific? I tried to add a record after I migrated on it however it just keep on rolling back.

Comment: I suppose that you need to set a PK for that table.

Comment: you mean an index to tha fieldt? like this one add_index("students", "student_id") ???

Comment: Testing this out.

Comment: You cannot auto increment then starting from 1000?

Comment: This is what I did awhile ago and no luck.